# Is there any way to retrieve file name using Python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, file, ubuntu

In a Linux directory, I have several numbered files, such as "day1" and "day2". My goal is to write a code that retrieves the number from the files and add 1 to the file that has the biggest number and create a new file. So, for example, if there are files, 'day1', 'day2' and 'day3', the code should read the list of files and add 'day4'. To do so, at least I need to know how to retrieve the numbers on the file name.

Comment: Look into the `os` module.

Comment: So your question is how to get the filename, or how to parse the number from inside a string (such as a filename)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get all the file names, remove the "day" prefix, convert the remaining characters to integers, and take the maximum.
From there, it's just a matter of incrementing the number and appending it to the same prefix:

```
import os
max_file = max([int(f[3:]) for f in os.listdir('some_directory')])
new_file = 'day' + str(max_file + 1)
```

Comment: Your code is not reusable if an other pattern is required. (3 is a magic number here.) Also the directory could contain files that don't match the pattern, but that's more of an extra.

Answer (score 0):

Get all files with the `os` module/package (don't have the exact command handy) and then use `regex`(package) to get the numbers. If you don't want to look into regex you could remove the letters  from your string with `replace()` and convert that string with `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

Glob would be good for this. It is kind of regex, but specially for file search and simpler. Basically you just use * as a wildcard, and you can select numbers too. Just google what it exactly is. It can be pretty powerful and is native to the bash shell for example.

```
for glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

pattern = "day"
last_file_number = max(map(lambda f: int(f[len(pattern):]), glob(pattern + "[0-9]*")))
Path("%s%d" % (pattern, last_file_number + 1)).touch()
```

You can also see that I use pathlib here. This is a library to deal with the file system in an OOP manner. Some people like, some don't.

So, a little disclaimer: Glob is not as powerful as regex. Here `daydream` for example won't be matched, but `day0dream` would still be matched. You can also try `day*[0-9]`, but then `daydream0` would still be matched.  Off course you can also use `day[0-9]` if you know you stay below double digits. So, if your use case requires this, you can use glob and filter down with regex.